# Algorithm to space/filter Google Maps Markers for readability?

Tags: android, algorithm, google-maps-markers

In my Android app I plot airports on Google Maps. When zoomed out far, the density gets very high. I'm familiar with marker clustering libraries, but would rather have a solution where a somewhat even distribution of airports is shown, leaving out overlapping ones, and when you zoom in more airports are filled in as needed.  Thanks for any tips on this.

Comment: What would "overlapping" mean in terms of an airport?

Comment: Good point. For my case it's the airport ID or weather data associated with that airport. Basically text (as a bitmap) of changing length. Love your book!

Comment: "text (as a bitmap)" -- meaning that you're rendering the text yourself to a bitmap, so you know the size in pixels? "Love your book!" -- thanks!

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm doing.

Comment: For now, I decided to limit the query result to 100 random airports, which more or less gives me what I need. When zoomed out, the map isn't crowded. When zoomed in, all airports are showing. I'll see if I can come up with some algorithm to create a more even spacing between displayed markers.

Answer (score 0):

Clustering is exactly what you need.

You just need to:

- position cluster at the same `LatLng` as one of the markers in this cluster
- use the same icon for cluster as for regular markers

Taking as an example Android Maps Extensions, which I'm the most familiar with, you would have to modify its code in [ClusterMarker.java](https://github.com/mg6maciej/android-maps-extensions/blob/develop/android-maps-extensions/src/com/androidmapsextensions/impl/ClusterMarker.java#L75-L81) from

```
private LatLng calculateClusterPosition() {
    LatLngBounds.Builder builder = LatLngBounds.builder();
    for (DelegatingMarker m : markers) {
        builder.include(m.getPosition());
    }
    return builder.build().getCenter();
}
```

to something like

```
private LatLng calculateClusterPosition() {
    return markers.get(0).getPosition();
}
```

or a bit more sophisticated algorithm, which calculates the center and then iterates over markers again to find the nearest marker and use its position.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I'm trying to avoid using a clustered marker, but instead reduce the number of markers displayed on a given zoom level until all are displayed when zoomed in closely. It makes sense in my mind, maybe not in reality...

Answer (score 0):

Make an ordered list of point-radius pairs as follows. Choose an arbitrary point and put it first on the list, with radius infinity. While there exist points not on the list, choose the one that maximizes the minimum distance to a point on the list. Append it to the list, with the radius equal to that maximum.

Now, when you need to display points with minimum inter-point distance r, take points from the beginning of the list until the radius drops below r.